# cannot install visual studio 11 preview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I use vista sp2 and have vs 2005/8/10 installed.

I try to install vs 11 preview using the web installer but immediately get a message "setup blocked" (see image). the linked log just has many lines like

```
[1424:1894][2011-09-17T22:13:51.749+02:00]: Detected package: netfx_dtpmsi_1048, state: Present, cached: No
```

any idea?

[image]

Comment: You're not on [vista started edition](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27538#system-requirements), are you?

Comment: Like @Jimmy mentioned (and the download page confirms) Vista is not supported by Visual Studio 11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe Vista is not supported by the Visual Studio 11 Preview; the published system requirements are different from all of the internal messaging.  You need Windows 7 or newer.  I recall that older systems haven't been supported on internal builds for the last couple months.

(Full disclosure: I work on one of the Visual Studio teams.)

Comment: The download page confirms your statement, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543